# How to disable absolute path generation in laravel-vite

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vite

Good afternoon! The problem is that vite generates js bundles and substitutes absolute paths in the HTML docment. How can I disable this?

these are the pathways generated by vite

```html
<link rel="preload" as="style" href="http://localhost:8080/build/assets/appaecd1ae2.css">
<link rel="modulepreload" href="http://localhost:8080/build/assets/app-4ed993c7.js">
<link rel="modulepreload" href="http://localhost:8080/build/assets/app-b8ba75b4.js">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8080/build/assets/app-aecd1ae2.css">
<script type="module" src="http://localhost:8080/build/assets/app-4ed993c7.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="http://localhost:8080/build/assets/app-b8ba75b4.js"></script>
```

Note it includes the **host http://localhost:8080** on the way. I wish it did not. But the attempts that are given in the documentation do not help me

here's my full vite.config.js What's my mistake?

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/sass/app.scss',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js',
        },
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, if `ASSET_URL` is not set, then Laravel will default to the app's URL.

Solution: Set `ASSET_URL` in `.env`

```
ASSET_URL=/
```